# How to Export DataFrame as Excel in Url Location

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, iis-7

I need Export my Dataframe to a server location, So that when my API got triggered from outside of my server, it will export to my url location. my codes are on on IIS SERVER.

```
url = "http//10.2.6.78:8063/folder1/folder2/folder3/"
```

I tried:

```
full_url = "url" + "file_name.xlsx"
df.to_excel(r'full_url', index=False) --error
```

os.error [error 22] invalid arguement.

Comment: first of all `full_url` should be `url + "file_name.xlsx"`. Currently you are treating url as part of your string. variables in python should not be quoted or they will be treated as string literals.

Comment: @d_kennetz i have updated the question, please look into it.

Comment: you are still quoting variables which is not correct. in your example the variable `full_url` will be treated as `"urlfile_name.xlsx"` and the string you are passing for df.to_excel is `"full_url"`.